# How to add an attribute to a link in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to add a attribute to the following code using jquery...

Exiting Button Code:

```
<div class="wp-picker-container">
    <a class="wp-color-result" tabindex="0" style="background-color: rgb(111, 183, 145);" title="Select Color"></a>
</div>
```

After click Exiting Code:

```
<div class="wp-picker-container">
    <a class="wp-color-result wp-picker-open" tabindex="0" style="background-color: rgb(111, 183, 145);" title="Select Color"></a>
</div>
```

**Need Output** as under like **add** **data-current="Current Color"** in

```
<a class="wp-color-result" tabindex="0" style="background-color: rgb(130, 6, 6);" title="Select Color" data-current="Current Color"></a>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like (not tested)

```
$(".wp-color-result").attr("data-current", "Current Color");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

However, if possible it might be a cleaner solution to use the `data()`-function instead, as the "data-current" attribute most likely has no meaning for the html-markup of your page. Using the `data()`-function would still allow you to use the data in your javascript-code.

`data()` would work like this:

```
$(".wp-color-result").data("data-current", "Current Color");
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by using the .data() method.

```
syntax: .data(key,value)

$('.wp-color-result').on('click',function() {

  $('.wp-color-result').data("current","current-color");

}
```

for more refer:http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: you have been faster with this information :)